# can not use findViewById method in public void function

Tags: java, android

im using fragment in android i have a fragment with `CustomersFragment` name in this fragment im using `findViewById` method wehen i using this method on `onCreateView` no problem , but when i using in `public void` function it has error , this is the my fragment code at the bottom

```
package com.androiddeft.navigationdrawer.fragments;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.androiddeft.navigationdrawer.MyListAdapter;
import com.androiddeft.navigationdrawer.R;
import com.androiddeft.navigationdrawer.Employee;
import com.androiddeft.navigationdrawer.DatabaseHelper;
import com.androiddeft.navigationdrawer.constants.NavigationDrawerConstants;

import java.util.List;


public class CustomersFragment extends Fragment {

    private Button btnSubmit;
    private Button btnCancel;
    private ListView listView;
    private MyListAdapter adapter;
    private EditText edtSearch, edtName, edtPhone, edtAddress;
    private int seletcedEmployeeId;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getActivity().setTitle(NavigationDrawerConstants.TAG_CUSTOMERS);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Create the view from XML layout.
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_customers, null);
        // Perform additional configuration on layout components here.
        Button btnAdd = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
        Button btnShowSearch = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_search);
        Button btnCloseSearch = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_close_search);
        Button btnDoSearch = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_do_search);
        btnCancel = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel);
        btnSubmit = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);

        edtSearch = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edt_search);
        edtName = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edt_employee_name);
        edtPhone = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edt_employee_phone);
        edtAddress = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edt_employee_address);

        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(onAddClicked);
        btnShowSearch.setOnClickListener(onShowSearchClicked);
        btnCloseSearch.setOnClickListener(onCloseSearchClicked);
        btnDoSearch.setOnClickListener(onDoSearchClicked);
        btnCancel.setOnClickListener(onCancelbuttonClicked);

        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        refreshList();
        return view;
    }
    private void refreshList() {
        List<Employee> employees = new DatabaseHelper(this).getListOfEmployees();
        adapter = new MyListAdapter(this, employees);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void editEmployee(Employee employee) {
        findViewById(R.id.lin_add_search).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.add_edit_employee).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(onEditEmployeeSubmit);
        edtName.setText(employee.getName());
        edtPhone.setText(employee.getPhone());
        edtAddress.setText(employee.getAddress());
        seletcedEmployeeId = employee.getId();
    }

    private View.OnClickListener onAddClicked = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            findViewById(R.id.lin_add_search).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            findViewById(R.id.add_edit_employee).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(onNewEmployeeSubmit);
        }
    };

    private View.OnClickListener onShowSearchClicked = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            findViewById(R.id.lin_add_search).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            findViewById(R.id.search_bar).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    };

    private View.OnClickListener onCloseSearchClicked = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            findViewById(R.id.lin_add_search).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            findViewById(R.id.search_bar).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            edtSearch.setText("");
            refreshList();
        }
    };

    private View.OnClickListener onDoSearchClicked = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String input = edtSearch.getText().toString();
            if (input.length() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "لطفا قسمتی از نام کارمند را بنویسید", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            List<Employee> employees = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity()).searchByName(input);
            adapter = new MyListAdapter(getActivity(), employees);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), employees.size() + " کارمند پیدا شد", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

    private View.OnClickListener onCancelbuttonClicked = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            edtName.setText("");
            edtPhone.setText("");
            edtAddress.setText("");
            findViewById(R.id.lin_add_search).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            findViewById(R.id.add_edit_employee).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    };

    private View.OnClickListener onNewEmployeeSubmit = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (edtName.getText().length() == 0 || edtPhone.getText().length() == 0 || edtAddress.getText().length() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "لطفا اطلاعات را وارد کنید", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            Employee employee = new Employee();
            employee.setName(edtName.getText().toString());
            employee.setPhone(edtPhone.getText().toString());
            employee.setAddress(edtAddress.getText().toString());
            new DatabaseHelper(getActivity()).addNewEmployee(employee);
            refreshList();
            btnCancel.performClick();
        }
    };

    private View.OnClickListener onEditEmployeeSubmit = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (edtName.getText().length() == 0 || edtPhone.getText().length() == 0 || edtAddress.getText().length() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "لطفا اطلاعات را وارد کنید", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            Employee employee = new Employee();
            employee.setId(seletcedEmployeeId);
            employee.setName(edtName.getText().toString());
            employee.setPhone(edtPhone.getText().toString());
            employee.setAddress(edtAddress.getText().toString());
            new DatabaseHelper(getActivity()).editEmployee(employee);
            refreshList();
            btnCancel.performClick();
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Which line causes the error? And what is the entire error message?

Comment: Each findViewById method in the public void function is error message : cannot resolve method 'findviewbyid(int)'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android developers commonly work with two methods named `findViewById()`. One of them is part of the `Activity` class and is usually invoked like this:

```
public void myMethod() {
    View myView = findViewById(R.id.myView);
}
```

The other is part of the `View` class, and is usually invoked like this:

```
public void myMethod(View root) {
    View myView = root.findViewById(R.id.myView);
}
```

However, there's no `findViewById()` method in the `Fragment` class, so you must use the `View` method instead. You're already doing that in your `onCreateView()`:

> ```
> @Override
> public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_customers, null);
>     Button btnAdd = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
>                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ```

However, later on you have this:

> ```
> public void editEmployee(Employee employee) {
>     findViewById(R.id.lin_add_search).setVisibility(View.GONE);
>     ^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ```

Again, the `Fragment` class has no `findViewById()` method, so this won't compile. Usually the workaround is to call `getView().findViewById()`. The `getView()` method returns the same `View` instance you returned from `onCreateView()`, so it will work just fine.

Something like this:

```
public void editEmployee(Employee employee) {
    getView().findViewById(R.id.lin_add_search).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```